# Exclude from resultset based on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the following table FOO;

```
| Org | Status |
| X   | CLOSED |
| X   | OPEN   |
| Y   | OPEN   |
| Y   | CLOSED |
```

How can I select all the records **except** where org = Y **and** status = CLOSED

So the resultset looks like:

```
| Org | Status |
| X   | CLOSED |
| X   | OPEN   |
| Y   | OPEN   |
```

Comment: where not (org = Y and status = CLOSED)

Comment: or, where org <> y or status <> closed

Comment: This gets a liitle more complicated, in case Org or Status can be null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this either of these ways:

```
WHERE (org, status) <> ('Y','CLOSED')
```

```
WHERE NOT (org = 'Y' AND status = 'CLOSED')
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select * from Table where Org != 'Y' and Status != 'CLOSED'
```

Comment: This works as well, but I can only accept one answer. Thanks!